# How do I display NYC community specific data on an interactive map without longitude/latitude coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, data, coordinate-system, cartography, carto

I have downloaded the NY Department of Sanitation's Monthly Tonnage Collection data from https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/DSNY-Monthly-Tonnage-Data/ebb7-mvp5#revert and I want to use this information to create an interactive map using CartoDB.

The problem is this data set does not contain long/lat coordinate data and thus cannot be mapped. Also, the smallest spatial denomination provided in the data set is community/district which means I probably need several coordinates to map each community/district.

I'm new to making interactive maps and GIS in general. What's the best way for me to proceed? Should I pluck out appropriate coordinates for each community/district and push them into the data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need coordinates or to join that data with existing polygons/points.
A quick look at your data shows that it is broken down into boroughs or district numbers.

My next step would be to [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) this data in ArcGIs or QGIS (whatever solution you have available to you) to either the boroughs or districts. This will allow you to visualize the districts (polgyons) with the tonnage data attached. [CartoDB](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html) allows you to upload your data in multiple formats. Here, I think your best bet would be to upload as a shapefile(SHP).

[NYC Community Districts](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/communitydistrictsny/a64w-at62)

[NYC Bouroughs](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/data?browseSearch=borough)

Let me know if this is unclear, or if you can provide additional information about what programs you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm currently working to join the two datasets using CartoDB.